# Heroku Failed to Install gems via bundler error with Publify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, publify

I am trying to host a RoR app with Publify gem via heroku. However I keep getting the following error. I have followed the instructions on Publify's github page concerning heroku, https://github.com/publify/publify. Another interesting thing is that it runs perfectly on my own server (rails s), signalling that something is wrong with the environment in the gemfile.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here are the errors I am receiving (heroku push) :

```
Your version of git is 1.9.3. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
Checking for app files to sync... done, 590 files needed
Uploading: 100.0% (ETA: 0s)
Launching build process...  done
Preparing app for compilation... done
Fetching buildpack... done
Detecting buildpack... done, Buildkit+Ruby
Fetching cache... empty
Compiling app...
  Compiling for Ruby
  Compiling Ruby/Rails
sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
 !
    ERROR: There was an error parsing your Gemfile, we cannot continue
    ERROR: Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
    ERROR: troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
    ERROR: /tmp/compile_unHgf/Gemfile:19:in `eval_gemfile': You need to configure config/database.yml first (RuntimeError)
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:36:in `eval_gemfile'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:10:in `evaluate'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:26:in `build'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:153:in `definition'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/cli/platform.rb:10:in `block in run'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:69:in `silence'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/cli/platform.rb:9:in `run'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:358:in `platform'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:9:in `start'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/gems/bundler-1.6.3/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    ERROR: from /tmp/d20150118-87-1khnax5/bundler-1.6.3/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
 !
ERROR: Build failed, exited 1
```

Since the problem has been caused by the gemfile here is mine,

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

if ENV["HEROKU"]
  ruby '2.1.3'

  gem "pg"
  gem "thin" # Change this to another web server if you want (ie. unicorn, passenger, puma...)
  gem "rails_12factor"
else

  require 'yaml'
  env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || 'development'
  dbfile = File.expand_path("../config/database.yml", __FILE__)

  unless File.exists?(dbfile)
    if ENV['DB']
      FileUtils.cp "config/database.yml.#{ENV['DB'] || 'postgres'}", 'config/database.yml'
    else
      raise "You need to configure config/database.yml first"
    end
  end

  conf = YAML.load(File.read(dbfile))
  environment = conf[env]
  adapter = environment['adapter'] if environment
  raise "You need define an adapter in your database.yml or set your RAILS_ENV variable" if adapter == '' || adapter.nil?
  case adapter
  when 'sqlite3'
    gem 'sqlite3'
  when 'postgresql'
    gem 'pg'
  when 'mysql2'
    gem 'mysql2'
  else
    raise "Don't know what gem to use for adapter #{adapter}"
  end
end

gem 'rails', '~> 4.1.7'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'bluecloth', '~> 2.1'
gem 'coderay', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.8'
gem 'addressable', '~> 2.1', :require => 'addressable/uri'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 3.8.1', :require => 'mini_magick'
gem 'uuidtools', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'flickraw-cached'
gem 'rubypants', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'rake', '~> 10.3.2'
#gem 'acts_as_list'
#gem 'acts_as_tree_rails3'
gem 'fog'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails', :branch => 'rails3'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'akismet', '~> 1.0'
gem 'twitter', '~> 5.6.0'

gem "jquery-rails", "~> 3.1.0"
gem "jquery-ui-rails", "~> 5.0.2"

gem 'rails-timeago', '~> 2.0'

gem 'rails_autolink', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'dynamic_form', '~> 1.1.4'

gem 'non-stupid-digest-assets'

# removed from Rails-core as Rails 4.0
gem 'actionpack-page_caching', '~> 1.0.2'
gem 'rails-observers', '~> 0.1.2'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', " ~> 4.0.3"
  gem 'coffee-rails', " ~> 4.0.1"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'factory_girl', '~> 4.5.0'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
end

# Install gems from each theme
Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'themes', '**', "Gemfile")) do |gemfile|
  eval(IO.read(gemfile), binding)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the part of the `Gemfile` that you want to use aka the `if ENV["HEROKU"]` block is not being executed. instead, the `else` block is invoked which raises the error in the snippet of the log you posted.

there are several possible causes of this that i'm going to write down in order of probablity

- you did not set `heroku config:set HEROKU=true` as explained in the publify documentation
- heroku ignores the environment variable
- the custom build-pack you are using interferes with what you are trying to achieve
- something else is broken